# Access af:table values from JavaScript array (for google maps task)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf, oracle-adf

I have JSP page with af:table where latitude and longitude for google maps are stored. I am using [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/middleware/entry/integrating_google_maps_with_adf) and I know how to access latitude and longitude from output text (for one point). Now i need to do something similar with loop for all table rows. How can I achieve this?

I have JavaScript code which uses Google Maps API and can display many points on one map. Also I have longitude and latitude data in `af:table` (bindings), each table row has one point. My task is to take data from `af:table` and pass it to JavaScript.

May be it is better to use managed bean as you said. Firstly I will access binding data from managed bean. Then I have to pass this data to JavaScript method? Can you suggest some example? I have "Using JavaScript in ADF Faces Rich Client Applications"

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question, as the one you asked before...
Check my answer in the other Question [I want af:table values get in javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506981/i-want-aftable-values-get-in-javascript-array/18530173#18530173)