# I want af:table values get in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf

I have ADFRichTable and get `af:table` values into Javascript array.

I use Javascript code:

`document.getElementById("t1:49:ot3").innerHTML` is working
Because `document.getElementById("t1:50:ot3").innerHTML` is not working
`af:table` retrieve in 50 rows.

How I get af:table all values into Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ADF Javascript APIs, and you have to set your table attribute Client = true and then you can get all Table properties by using Javascript APIs in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e12046/oracle/adf/view/js/component/rich/data/AdfRichTable.html), and follow this [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/message/9502354#9502354) for what Javascript you can do